# Getting Model Data for XAML Preview

Tags: json, xaml, xamarin, mocking

I am using an JSON reader for my model data

```
var data = await JsonApiReader.ReadDataAsync(this.id);
```

This data will be read on runtime from an API. But, I want to have a preview in my XAML Form in Xamarin. So, how can I mock this data? For the Unit-Tests I still have an offline JSON file which I could use.

Comment: It doesn't work like that you can only add harcode data to it for now

Comment: Why can't you just use the same offline JSON file? Just add it to your app project and you can use compiler directives so the code that loads `data` from the offline JSON file is used when debugging, but the JSOMN from the API will be used for Release builds. More on conditional compilation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT is it possible to have an preview compiler directive, too?

Comment: not sure what you mean by preview compiler directive? You can create a preview configuration that defines a __PREVIEW__ symbol and then test for that in your source code using a compiler directive. here's a blog on build configurations and how to create new ones: https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mock my ViewModel when is in DesignMode

```
if (DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled) {
    var json = File.ReadAllText("path/to/file.json");
    var mock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(json);

    BindContent(mock);
} else {
    var data = await JsonApiReader.ReadDataAsync(this.id);
    BindContent(data);
}
```

That's working fine for me!